# compiling error cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I am trying to compile this code, but I get the error message cannot find symbol.
I couldn't figure out what is going on. The thing is I already have another code made called `MadLibIO` and I don't get why it can't be read.

```
public class MadLibGame
{
  private MadLibIO myTools;
  Toolkit     myTools;      
  Scanner     keyboard;
  Word        manipulate;
}
```

---

```
MadLibGame.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        private MadLibIO myTools;
                ^
  symbol:   class MadLibIO
  location: class MadLibGame
```

Comment: Did you import `MadLibIO`?

Comment: If `MadLibIO` is in another package, you must import it.

Comment: also as a side note: you have MadLibIO and Toolkit both named myTools.

Comment: `MadLibIO `should be on classpath.